# Django middleware process_template_response show middleware response and then view response

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-middleware

Is there a way that first I show my middleware process_template_response response by taking view context data and then show the original view response.

I had defined a middleware,

```
def process_template_response(self, request, response):
    return render(request, 'accounts/form.html', {})
```

And my view is,

```
def view_func(request, product_id):
    ...
    ... 
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'accounts/home.html', {})
```

Comment: I did not get that, what did you mean by `show my middleware process_template_response response by taking view context data and then show the original view response.`?

Comment: @ruddra I mean as soon as the view has done its execution middleware process_template_response is called which will take context data of view and using that show the HttpResponse of middleware and after it done with its execution show the view render template. I am not sure whether this can happen so just asking ?

Comment: if you mean render the html 2 times, I don't think its possible.